# Authenticating a user via the Okta Auth API and redirect the user but I don't get a session cookie

Tags: okta, okta-api

I have the following scenario. If the user doesn't have a valid session cookie, the application A is redirected to another application B. In Application B, I show a login form to the user and after I get their credentials I authenticate the user and redirect the user via Okta back to Application A but I don't see any session cookies. Is there something I'm missing? See below:

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
public void authenticate() {
    var oktaClient = newOktaClient("my_API_Key", "myportal.oktapreview.com/");
    var authClient = oktaClient.GetAuthClient();
    var res = authClient.Authenticate(loginCtrl.UserName,loginCtrl.Password);

    var uri = string.format("https://myportal.oktapreview.com/login/sessionCookieRedirect?token={0}&redirectUrl=http://localhost/myapp", res.SessionToken);
    Response.Redirect(uri);
}
```

After I redirect with the sessionCookieRedirect, the user is redirected as expected to http://localhost/myapp but when I look in the browser I don't see any session cookie.